# unbound method get_queryset() must be called with WorkoutList instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am implementing DRF's Pagination over my existing web service (RESTful API). Now I learned from the docs of DRF Pagination that pagination is authomatically applied to ListCreateAPIView , only need to add some of the lines in settings.py file.

So I did the changes according to the documentation and for my webservice I wanted my queryset to be dynamic. 
Below are the changes done:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/workouts/get/$',
        ListCreateAPIView.as_view(WorkoutList.get_queryset(), serializer_class=WorkoutSerializer), name='list'),
```

**views.py**

```
class WorkoutList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset =  Workout.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkoutSerializer
    permission_classes = (UserPermissions,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        workout_instance = WorkoutList()
        workout_instance.get_queryset()
        query_params = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.dict()
        if 'date' in query_params and 'exclude_app_install_time' in query_params:
            query_set = Workout.objects.filter(created__contains=date).exclude(
                app_install_time=query_params['exclude_app_install_time'])
        else:
            query_set = {}
        return query_set

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            workouts = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = WorkoutSerializer(workouts, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

PS : I have stackoverflowed (pun intented) the problem but couldn't find the right solution(s).

Also I want to implement OffsetLimitPagination in the DRF. A small example link will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple of very strange things here.

If you subclass a view, you should use that subclass in the urls, not a strange mash-up of the original class and a method from the subclass. So:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/workouts/get/$',
        WorkoutList.as_view(serializer_class=WorkoutSerializer), name='list'),
```

Once you've fixed that, you'll get into an infinite recursion inside your get_queryset method. Again, when you subclass, if you want to call the original implementation you use `super`; you don't initialize another instance of the current class and try to call that method, because it'll be the *same* method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_set = super(WorkoutList, self).get_queryset()
```

**Edit** I guess the pagination doesn't work because you are starting from a blank Workout query rather than using the returned value from the super call. So you should do:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_set = super(WorkoutList, self).get_queryset()
    query_params = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.dict()
    if 'date' in query_params and 'exclude_app_install_time' in query_params:
        query_set = query_set.filter(created__contains=date).exclude(
            app_install_time=query_params['exclude_app_install_time'])
    return query_set
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you're also overriding the `list` method. There's no need to do that; remove that method altogether.

Comment: I totally missed out that I have to add user's Id i.e pk from the URL . I tried `Workout.objects.filter(created__contains=date,user = self.args['pk'])` . But couldn't get it to working

Comment: Surely `pk` is the primary key of the WorkoutList, not the User? I guess you want `user=self.request.user`. If that doesn't work, please post a new question.

Comment: i read one of your answer on another question. I just used `self.kwargs['pk']`